# Composer style and printed style are different (minimized)

Tags: qgis, style, print-composer, printing

composer styles and printed image styles dont match. I tried printing with `#Save out
    dpi = comp.printResolution()
    dpmm = dpi / 25.4
    width = int(dpmm * comp.paperWidth())
    height = int(dpmm * comp.paperHeight())
    image = QImage(QSize(width, height), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    image.setDotsPerMeterX(dpmm * 1000)
    image.setDotsPerMeterY(dpmm * 1000)
    image.fill(0)
    imagePainter = QPainter(image)
    comp.renderPage(imagePainter, 0)
    imagePainter.end()
    image.save(plaan, "jpg")`
and `img = comp.printPageAsRaster(0,QSize(2970,2100),250)
     img.save(plaan, "jpg")`

Canvas and composer window display picture like this(that was purpose too):[image: styles from composer and canvas]
Printed image has styles somehow minimized. Tried as well from QGis and from standalone app as pdf and raster. Anyway result is not satisfying. Is there any additional option I can change to get output like I have in composer?
[image]
In my output styles are hard to distinguish, but I can change them, cause Forest Management Plan stylesheet is regularized by act.